# How to have items in flexbox only take content width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container which has a display flex property and i set the flex-wrap to wrap.

Problem I am having is that I am getting to much space between items.

My code:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">Ss</div>
  <div class="child">Very very very long text text text</div>
  <div class="child">Small</div>
  <div class="child">Medium</div>
</div>
```

Image:

[image]

Can find code in action here:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvwf5g9m/9/)

Comment: remove the flex-grow property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flex-grow` property distributes free space on the line, based on the value applied.

If you give all items `flex-grow: 1`, each item will consume equal space.

Since you have two items with `flex-grow: 1`, they split the space on the line 50-50.

Remove `flex-grow`. Use margins or padding.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the flex grow and add a gap to create a bit of a space between items.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  gap: 5px; /*emphasized text*/ 
}

.child {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```